# Стандартная библиотека в С++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, библиотеки

Нужно описать код библиотеки #include "vcl.h".

Как лучше его описать на 1 страницу максимум информации. И как посмотреть, что какой код содержит в себе vcl.h?

Comment: Что значит "описать код"?

Comment: я имею в виду, как просмотреть всю библиотеку vcl? какой в ней код?

Comment: Код в ней программный. Домашнее задание?

Comment: вообщем, в visual studio, можно было просмотреть содержимое подключенной библиотеки, нажатием правой кнопкой мыши по ней... в а как это сделать в C/C++ Builder? вот этот код мне и нужен...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите в Program Files (или Program Files(х86)) папку С++ Builder'a.
Хрустальный шар подсказывает, что она может лежать в папке Borland))

Там ищите папку include в ней находите нужный вам .h . При клике он скорее всего в IDE и откроется, но в крайнем случае пробуйте блокнот.

Builder'a под руками нет, точно посмотреть не могу.